# Cumulative distribution problem

Tags: probability, statistics

I have a cumulative distribution function where $X$ is a **discrete** random variable:
$F(x)=0$ for $x<1$ and $F(x)=1-\bigl(\frac{1}{2}\bigr)^{\lfloor x \rfloor}$ for $x\ge 1$.

I want to know if $P(3<X\le5) = P(3\le X\le5$)?

Or is $P(X<5)$ the same as $P(X\le 5)?$

I know that for a cumulative distribution function, $F(x)$, $P(a<X<b)=F(b)-F(a)$ but I don't know if the fact that we're using a floor affects anything? What about the fact that this cumulative distribution function represents a **discrete** random variable $X$? I would think that if we're including $X=3$ vs not including it, we just take $P(3< X\le5)+P(X=3).$ Now if I knew this cumulative distribution function was for a **continuous** random variable, then I think $P(3<X\le5)$ would indeed equal $P(3\le X\le5)$ because $P(X=3)$ would be $0$ in the **continuous** case. Other than that, I could use some help please. Thanks so much

Comment: $P(X \lt 5) \ne P(X \leq 5)$ as value of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ changes when $x$ is the next positive integer. In fact $P(X \lt 5) = P(X \leq 4)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $P(a < X \le b) = F(b)-F(a)$.

We can see that $F$ has discontinuity at positive integer.

It is the geometric distribution with probability $\frac12$.  Hence $P(3<X \le 5) \ne P(3 \le X \le 5)$ and $P(X<5)\ne P(X \le 5)$.

Comment: So if $P(3<X\le5)$ is $F(b)-F(a)$ what does that make $P(3\le X\le 5)$?

Comment: We have to add back $P(X=3)$.

Comment: That’s what my guess was (I put it in my original question). How do I get $P(X=3)$ from the cumulative distribution function given? Thank you so much for the help

Comment: This is geometric distribution, for this example, $P(3 \le X \le 5) = P(2 < X \le 5)=F(5)-F(2)$. If you are just interested in $P(X=3)$, you can also compute it using the geometric PMF formula or $P(X=3)=F(3)-F(2)$.